# Не помню email домена

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

Есть мой домен, и на нем раньше был E-mail ящик. Из-за того, что не продлили хостинг, он пропал.

На мой тот ящик падают письма важные, но вот сам меил я узнать не могу, и не помню( Как можно отследить, на какой логин почты падает Email?

То есть, к примеру, есть домен *site.com*, и почта летит на *undefined@site.com*. Как можно узнать этот undefined? И возможно ли это?

Comment: А кто и как хостит сервер почты?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы перенесли домен на какой-то другой хостинг и на нем поднята почта? В этом случае сообщения обо всех попытках связаться с вашим почтовым сервером должны помещаться в логи.

1. Можно связаться с службой поддержки, чтобы они проанализировали логи вашего сервера и сообщили обо всех попытках связаться с несуществующими почтовыми ящиками.
2. Многие провайдеры предоставляют услуги по сбору таких вот неприкаянных писем с последующим их помещением в отдельный почтовый ящик.

Или у вас свой собственный сервер? В этом случае нужно больше подробностей, для начала операционную систему и дистрибутив.